# Cannot delete an old iCloud account from my IPhone

Tags: icloud, iphone

I am trying to delete an account from my iPnone.  When I go to Settings -iCloud and try to Delete the account, it asks for the Apple ID.  I do not know the Apple ID and this is from a previous email account?

Answer (score 1):

You can remove an iCloud account by restoring the device using iTunes: connect it to iTunes and click Restore.

However, this does not disable the device's Find My iPhone status — if Find My iPhone is enabled on the iCloud account on the device then the device will be under Activation Lock and will require you to enter your Apple ID to use the device.